# apply functions for xts

Tags: excel, r, xts, zoo

My data is currently an xts or zoo object of daily stock prices per row and each column is a different company.

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols("AAPL;MSFT;YHOO")
closePrices <- merge(Cl(AAPL),Cl(MSFT),Cl(YHOO))
```

I am still new to R and need some assistance reproducing this [Excel function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJ7mi.png).  My first thought was to split the function into numerator and denominator, and then compute the index:

```
dailyDiff <- abs(diff(closePrices,1))
numerJ <- diff(closePrices,10)
denomJ <- as.xts(rollapply(dailyDiff,11, sum))
idx <- abs(numerJ/denomJ)
```

This was great because the values for each portion were accurate, but are aligned by incorrect dates for denomJ. For example, the tail of numerJ goes to 6/21/2012, while the tail of denomJ goes to 6/14/2012.

The output that I am looking for is:

- 6/21/2012 = .11
- 6/20/2012 = .27
- 6/19/2012 = .46
- 6/18/2012 = .39
- 6/15/2012 = .22

Comment: Now that I've made your example reproducible, could you please re-visit your question and provide some expected output?  Also, please describe what you mean by "the dates are wrong" and "idx contains the wrong values".

Comment: thank you! edits made. hope it clarifies that my two xts/zoo objects, numerJ and denomJ, are producing the accurate numbers (numerJ @ 6/21 =5.95 and denomJ @ 6/21 =53.25). yet as a consequence of the rollapply function, aligns to date values that I do not want.

Comment: I do not understand your question at all.  Your Excel function makes it even more confusing to me because it's so poorly labeled. Re: your recent comment, I don't see the number 53.25 anywhere.  That said, based on your complaint about date alignment, I'm almost certain that the answer is that you need to use `align=right` in your `rollapply` call (or use the `rollapplyr` wrapper). See `?rollapply`

Comment: Sorry if I am unclear. align = "right" hasn't worked for me. Please let me clarify. For each day, the numerator is the difference between today's price and the price of the stock ten day's prior (closePrice[i] - closePrice[i-10]). The denominator is sum of the daily differences in the date range; sum(dailyDiff[i]-dailyDiff[i-10]). So for the last observation in denomJ, the value is 53.25 because (8.07 + 1.67 + 1.63 + 11.65 +2.60 + 0.63 + 4.00 + 4.99 + 9.15 + 8.60 + 0.26) = 53.25. I'm thinking the solution is in writing a function that accepts (x,y), but not sure. Thanks for taking a look!

Comment: also, changed the link to the function in the original post. maybe that helps.

Comment: This still is not easily reproducible so one can't be sure what is wanted but it may be that the problem is that your code did not specify the alignment in `rollapply` so you got `align = "center"` by default.  Maybe you want `align="left"` or `align="right"` in `rollapply` or maybe you want to `lag` it by some different amount.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to tell exactly what your problem is without exact data, but the problem appears to be with `rollapply`. `rollapply` will only apply the function to whole intervals unless the argument `partial` is set to `TRUE`. Consider the following example

```
require(zoo)
#make up some data
mat <- matrix(1:100,ncol=2)
colnames(mat) <- c("x1","x2")
dates <- seq.Date(from=as.Date("2010-01-01"),length.out=50,by="1 day")
zoo.obj <- zoo(mat,dates)
#apply the funcitons
numerJ <- diff(zoo.obj,10)  #dates okay
denomJ <- rollapply(zoo.obj,11, sum,partial=TRUE)  #right dates
denomJ2 <- rollapply(zoo.obj,11,sum) #wrong dates
index <- abs(numerJ/denomJ)  #right dates
```

Comment: thank you! i think the problem is with rollapply, too. i think the most appropriate solution will come in the form of a function which accepts (x,y), but i am still not sure...

Answer (score 2):

You can use a combination of `diff` and either `runSum` or `rollapplyr`

```
#Get the data
library(quantmod)
getSymbols("AAPL")
```

I think this is what you're trying to do (note the use of the `lag` argument to `diff.xts`, and the `n` argument to `runSum`)

```
out <- diff(Cl(AAPL), lag=10) / runSum(abs(diff(Cl(AAPL))), n=11)
tail(out['/2012-06-21'])
#           AAPL.Close
#2012-06-14 -0.1047297
#2012-06-15  0.2176938
#2012-06-18  0.3888185
#2012-06-19  0.4585821
#2012-06-20  0.2653782
#2012-06-21  0.1117371
```

**Edit**

Upon closer review of your question, I do not understand why `rollapplyr` is not the answer you're looking for.  If I take your code, exactly as is, except I change `rollapply` to `rollapplyr`, it looks to me like it's exactly the output you're looking for.

```
dailyDiff <- abs(diff(closePrices,1))
numerJ <- diff(closePrices,10)
denomJ <- as.xts(rollapplyr(dailyDiff,11, sum))
idx <- abs(numerJ/denomJ)
#           AAPL.Close MSFT.Close YHOO.Close
#2012-06-14  0.1047297 0.03826531 0.06936416
#2012-06-15  0.2176938 0.35280899 0.25581395
#2012-06-18  0.3888185 0.33161954 0.31372549
#2012-06-19  0.4585821 0.47096774 0.34375000
#2012-06-20  0.2653782 0.32644628 0.23750000
#2012-06-21  0.1117371 0.18997912 0.10256410
```

Also, note that both `numerJ` and `denomJ` both end on the same date if you use `rollapplyr` (which is the same as using `rollapply` with `align="right"`)

```
end(numerJ); end(denomJ)
#[1] "2012-07-20"
#[1] "2012-07-20"
```

**Yahoo Bug**

Maybe the problem you're seeing is the yahoo bug where sometimes -- for example, right now -- yahoo duplicates the last (chronologically speaking) row of data.  If so, try deleting the duplicated row before attempting to use the data for your calculations.

```
tidx <- tail(index(closePrices), 2)
if(tidx[1] == tidx[2]) {
  closePrices <- closePrices[-NROW(closePrices), ]
}
```